# Reporting Services - Report reutilization

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have designed and tested a report and it's working fine.
After some refinements, we manage to reduce it so it takes only 1/8 of a page, so at 2 per "row" we can fit 4 rows in a regular A4 page.
Now, a requirement dropped out of nowhere saying that this report must be printed multiple times in a same page.

Is there a way to re-utilize my previous report as a template, maybe throw it into a "foreach"?

**EDIT 1**
I've managed to use the "subreport", what i need now is a way to add them on the fly, based on how many rows the dataset returns...

Comment: Take a look at `SubReport`, perhaps [this MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251765(v=vs.90).aspx) will be of use to you.

Comment: @Oceans tks, but the sub report part i kind figured out... what i'm having trouble is adding them on the fly... i'll edit the question...

Answer (score 0):

If each of the 8 reports has the same parameters, you can just create 8 subreports in one report.

Comment: yes they do, they are the same report layout replicated... but I don't know how many items will be generated... i know that I can fit a maximum of 8 per page... and depending on the size of some fields, less items are acceptable... like 6, 4 or even 2...

Comment: (Not sure about it, too lazy to check) I think it was possible to squeeze the subreport into the tablix/matrix - you can then limit the number of rows/columns on the fly to fit the page

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to place the subreport 8 times on your main report and define expressions whether to make them visible based on a parameter you provide.

It's not really that dynamic, but it'll get the job done. As you only want a single page filled, it shouldn't be much trouble.